# how do I access data in range data type in Elastisearch using painless script

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have the following mapping configuration

```
          "some_range": {
            "type": "integer_range"
          }
```

and it has data like the following

```
"some_range": [
            {
              "gte": 100,
              "lte": 200
            },
            {
              "gte": 300,
              "lte": 400
            }
}
```

I am trying to construct a query that will return a boolean field based on this range information for example the query looks something like this:

```
  "script_fields" : {
    "within_range" : {
      "script" : {
        "inline": "doc['some_range.gte'].value > params.my_range && doc['some_range.lte'].value < params.my_range",
        "lang": "painless",
        "params": {
          "my_range": 150
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

and the expected return looks like this

```
        "fields": {
          "within_range": [
            true
          ]
        }
```

but the query I tried gives me this error:

```
Fielddata is not supported on field [some_range] of type [integer_range]
```

I am wondering what is the correct way of writing the painless scripts and how do I access the fields in a range typed data structure in ElasticSearch

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?
I've exactly the same issue.